# Visual Studio Code only compiles when launched from project folder on Linux

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have Visual Studio Code installed in Ubuntu 20.04. I love how it works. I installed it from the tar ball. Same with the SDK. I just found that those appear to work better than installing from deb packages.

I created a desktop file so I could add Visual Studio Code to the dock and launch it that way, but what I've noticed is that projects won't compile. I get errors stating it can't find the project even though the errors are listing the folder where the items exist.

The only way I can get it to work is to:

1. Open a terminal.
2. Navigate to the folder where the project files reside.
3. Launch code from the command line.

Then it works. Otherwise, I get a pop-up error that says "The preLaunchTask 'build' terminated with exit code -2" and then the terminal window is filled with errors.

[image: Pop up dialog]

Here's the last of the error messages and then I opened up a terminal and it shows that I'm in the folder for the project and the csproj exists there:

[image: Output and Terminal]

This also happens if I install Visual Studio code from a repository. It seems launching it from the Unity desktop breaks something. But if I launch it from the command line in a terminal session from the folder where the project resides, then the problem goes away.

I can also reproduce this error from the command line if I launch Visual Studio Code from a different folder than the project I'm trying to compile.

Is this common? Just curious. I'm wondering if because when I launch it from the Unity desktop, it's launching under a different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working under 20.04. I must have done something wrong so I did a wipe of the .NET Core install and reinstalled it all using the bash shell script and then was able to install Code via Software Installer tool. Not sure why it didn't work before, but it works now.